# Difference between upper integral and lower integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I have the following problem:

> Let $f: [a,b]\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a bounded function. Prove that
>   $$\bar\int_a^b f-  \underline\int_a^b f=\bar\int_a^b w(f,x)dx$$

where $w(f, x)$ is the oscillation of $f$ on $x$. For a definition see here [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscillation_(mathematics)#Oscillation_of_a_function_at_a_point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscillation_%28mathematics%29#Oscillation_of_a_function_at_a_point)

I want to know if the following is correct:

Let $\epsilon>0$. For each $x$ there exist an open interval $I_x$ such that

$$w(f,I_x)-w(f,x)<\displaystyle\frac{\epsilon}{2(b-a)}$$

The family containing $I_x$ is an open cover of $[a,b]$. Since $[a,b]$ is compact there exist a finite subcover $I_{x_1},..., I_{x_n}$ wich cover $[a,b]$. Let $P$ a partition consisting on border points of $I_{x_i}$ that lie in $[a,b]$ and the points $a,b$. For this partition we have
$$w(f,I_{x_i})-M_i(w)\leq\displaystyle\frac{\epsilon}{2(b-a)}<\displaystyle\frac{\epsilon}{(b-a)}$$
then taking the sum we get

$$U(f,P)-L(f,P)-U(w,P)<\epsilon$$

since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary we have the result.

Is this fine?

Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: Where did you find this theorem ?

Comment: I found it in Curso de Análise Elon Lages Lima volumen I. A brazilian book.

Comment: I'm using exactly the same book and made a duplicate question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1926648/overline-int-ab-f-underline-int-ab-f-overline-int-ab?noredirect=1#comment3965601_1926648

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The theorem appears (for the first time ?) in de la Vallée-Poussin [*Cours d'Analyse Infinitésimale Tome I*](https://ia600302.us.archive.org/23/items/1903coursdanalys01lavauoft/1903coursdanalys01lavauoft.pdf) (1903), pp. 218-219. It contains some wrong arguments as was shown by S.Pollard in [*Note on a Proof in Vallée-Poussin's "Cours d'Analyse"*](https://ia600400.us.archive.org/31/items/messengerofmathe44cambuoft/messengerofmathe44cambuoft.pdf), Messenger of Math. Vol. 44 (1914), pp. 141-144.

I refer to the proof (similar to yours) contained in E.W.Hobson [*The Theory of Functions of a Real Variable and the Theory of Fourier's Series Vol. 1*](https://ia600201.us.archive.org/19/items/theoryfunctreal01hobsrich/theoryfunctreal01hobsrich.pdf) (1921), pp. 437-438. Till now I didn't find a more recent version.

Now your proof and my notes (in italics) avoiding some detail:

Let $\epsilon>0$ *and $\delta>0$*. For each $x$ there exist an open interval $I_x$ *of length less than $\delta$* such that

$$w(f,I_x)-w(f,x)<\displaystyle\frac{\epsilon}{b-a }$$

The family containing $I_x$ is an open cover of $[a,b]$. Since $[a,b]$ is compact there exist a finite subcover $I_{x_1},..., I_{x_n}$ wich cover $[a,b]$.$\;$ *(the existence of $P$ must be proved, see Hobson)* **Let $P$ a partition consisting of border points of $I_{x_i}$ that lie in $[a,b]$ and the points $a,b$.** For this partition we have
$$0\le w(f,I_{x_i})-M_i(w)<\displaystyle\frac{\epsilon}{(b-a)}$$
then taking the sum we get

$$0 \le U(f,P)-L(f,P)-U(w,P)<\epsilon$$

*For $\delta \rightarrow 0$*, since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, we have the result.